# How to restore empathy windows on Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, empathy

Somehow the main application window of my empathy application is gone and only shows me the contact list but not the account settings window so that I can no longer add instant messanger accounts or persons to an account. How can I restore that? I use GNOME Shell 3.6.2.

Comment: Does it come back when you just execute `empathy` again (from a terminal or via `Alt+F2`)?

Comment: No, neither works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Gnome 3.6.x apps have been ported to `GMenu` and as such the "menu" is only available from the main toolbar (it changes according to the focused app) , e.g. for `empathy`:

[image]

Comment: I am so blind I never looked at the top bar :-)